# "Retrieve a Signer Trust Certificate from a remote endpoint" in tomcat to consume\access\call soap service from another server in java/tomcat

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, webservice-client, client-certificates

In case of consuming a third party webservice, what kind of trust certificate are required?

Do we need to ask third party to give us certificate so that we can use in our tomcat to call a webservice?

I tried downloading the certificates from the web service endpoint over browser and imported them into self sign keystore and done the tomcat configuration too. but that is not working.

Tomcat configuration in server.xml

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" algorithm="SunX509" clientAuth="want"
            keyAlias="NodeDefaultTrustStore" keyPass="tomcat"
            keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/security/NodeDefaultTrustStore.jks"
            keystorePass="tomcat" keystoreType="jks" maxThreads="150" port="443"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
            secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

Errors what i am getting

```
Message:   Unable to retrieve user profile data available from XX User Component.
Context:   WSWS3713E: Connection to the remote host XXXX.XXX.com:443 failed.Received the following error: com.ibm.wsspi.channel.framework.exception.ChannelException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunX509 for provider IBMJSSE2
```

Comment: The `<Connector>` block is for HTTPS connections _to_ your Tomcat server _from_ clients like browsers; it has no relevance at all for outgoing connections. And not defaulting `[keymanager]algorithm` or `truststorealgorithm` makes sense only if you have customized your cryptoproviders, which is clearly beyond your ability, and setting a Sun^WOracle/OpenJDK-specific value on IBM Java as you did fails completely as you saw. If a common browser connects to the service without error then you probably don't need to do _anything_, the Java default will work. ...

Comment: ... And if you do need to do something, it depends on the software or middleware you use to make the outgoing connection, about which you said nothing. JAXWS? Axis? CXF? Some IBM lib I don't know about? basic HttpsURLConnection or HttpClient? other?

Comment: @Shakir Husain - Are you able to resolve this issue? I am getting same issue now.